# Cant understand scope issue here

Tags: javascript

I dont understand why/ how to accomplish this fairly simple thing. If someone could explain it that would be great.

```
function Module(config) {
  this.host = {Collapse: $('<a href="#" class="collapse">C</a>')};

  function EnableCollapse() {
    //I need to access host.Collapse here
    this.host.Collapse.hide(); // Throws error
    host.Collapse.hide(); //Throws error
  }
}
```

How do I access Collapse inside this function? Or should these work and perhaps i have something else wrong?

Comment: How are you executing the `EnableCollapse` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're calling `Module` as a constructor, you could make `EnableCollapse` a property of the object rendered.

```
function Module(config) {
    this.host = {
        Collapse: $('<a href="#" class="collapse">C</a>')
    };

    this.EnableCollapse = function () {

        this.host.Collapse.hide();
    }
}

var mod = new Module({...});

mod.EnableCollapse();
```

---

Otherwise, if you intend to keep `EnableCollapse` private, you manually set its `this` value.

```
function Module(config) {
    this.host = {
        Collapse: $('<a href="#" class="collapse">C</a>')
    };

    function EnableCollapse() {

        this.host.Collapse.hide();
    }

    EnableCollapse.call(this);
}
```

Ultimately, the value of `this` will depend on *how* you're calling `Module` and `Collapse`.

Comment: Thank you, i understand the difference in what im doing now!

Comment: How would i go about mixing the public and private functions? For instance i want to have a private function that is called when the object is instantiated that calls EnableCollapse that remains public?

Comment: @Zholen: You can either create a reference to the outer value of `this` (in Module) as shown in the other answer, or when you invoke your private function, set its `this` value manually using `.call`, then simply call `this.EnableCollapse()` from within. `function privateFunc() { /*do_something*/ this.EnableCollapse(); }   privateFunc.call( this );`

Answer (score 3):

```
function Module(config) {
  var that = this;
  that.host = {Collapse: $('<a href="#" class="collapse">C</a>')};

  function EnableCollapse() {
    //I need to access host.Collapse here
    that.host.Collapse.hide(); // Throws error
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You access Collapse inside the function via `this.host.Collapse`